# Vugen access to path to start recording dialog is denied

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

In Vugen im getting an error from the

> access to path C:\Program Files
>   (x86)HP\LoadRunner\Config\StartRecordingDialog is denied

.  How do I fix to begin recording?

Comment: Has it ever worked on this box or is this as new installation?

Comment: What LoadRunner version, what OS Version, and does your user have admin rights?